# Getting different keyboards for text input programmatically

Tags: android, input, keyboard, user-input

What should I do to get different input keyboards for text input in my Android. For example when I want to input text in Korean, I want a Korean KB. And if I want to do the same in Chinese, I want to get a Chinese keyboard. How do I do it programmatically? Any pointers will be greatly appreciated. Thanks.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This cannot be done due to security constraints. Look at [InputMethodManager:Security](http://developer.android.com/reference/android/view/inputmethod/InputMethodManager.html#Security)